# Remove trailing slash at the end of axios url request

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to do a request with axios, but it keeps adding a trailing slash right before my query parameters and so it stops working, I can't figure out for the life of me what the hell is its problem and I cant find any options in the config to remove it.

This is the url that I want to send request to

`http://localhost:3000/api/competition/player-joined?userId=${accounts[i].dbId}&competitionId=a80flwvap1lbhef3d704`

Axios sends request to this instead:

`http://localhost:3000/api/competition/player-joined/?userId=${accounts[i].dbId}&competitionId=a80flwvap1lbhef3d704`

There is a `/` right before the `?` being added by axios itself when sending the request.

This is a standalone js file that I am running with node.

The suggested questions that supposedly solve this issue DO NOT SOLVE THE ISSUE.

Also, Axios is automatically doing that, I am not giving it a string with a slash, so its not a matter of simple "replace string".

Comment: @Vanojx1 no it does not, I already saw this post.

Comment: Why would you close my question when what you are suggesting has nothing to do with my problem?

Comment: Voted to reopen, please add some reference code.

Comment: Sounds more like url rewriting on your server is causing this. If not, ditch axios and use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: @Besworks that turned out to be correct, I did manage to solve it a week ago when I had the issue. The problem turned out to be even more stupid than this (because I also did try fetch, it was behaving the same way), my URL was wrong, there was one more argument missing to make the URL valid, so yes. You are correct in your assumption and I was simply wrong with the URL itself. This is a Nextjs project, initially I thought its caused by Axios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be very simple.

As pointed the suggested answers were not helping, the problem was in an entirely different place and not with `axios`.

As I was testing I had also tried it with `fetch` but it was doing the same thing, and at some point I decided to try Postman, and it too was not working! But I knew that the URL itself is working, because I am using it in multiple places within my app and they all were working, except this new thing that I was developing, which eventually helped me find the problem.

The problem was that my URL itself was not valid!

`http://localhost:3000/api/competition/player-joined?...`

was supposed to be

`http://localhost:3000/api/competition/update/player-joined?...`

And as @Besworks suggested in a comment above, it was the server rewriting the URL.

The moment I fixed the URL, everything worked just fine.